# Can be camera exposure change in web app?

Tags: javascript, web, camera, brightness, exposure

Hi i want ask if there is way to change exposure( i only need change brighness) settings throw javascript. Using brightness throw pixels dont help, becouse i want use it to get wavelenght for spectrometer, that works corectly. Problem is when i getting intensive light than all rgb on that place get max rgb value.

Thanks for any help and answer.

I am using right know library:
https://webrtc.github.io/adapter/adapter-latest.js

```
var constraints = {video: {width: 1280, height: 960, facingMode: "user"}};
    const container = document.getElementById('webcam'),
    video = document.createElement('video');
    video.autoplay = true;
    container.appendChild(video);
    
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
    .then(stream =>{
        video.srcObject = stream;
      $('#heightIndicator').show()
      $('#webcam-msg').hide()
    })
    .then(() => new Promise(resolve => video.onloadedmetadata = resolve))
    .then(() => log(video.videoWidth +"x"+ video.videoHeight))
    .catch(e => log(e));

    var data;
    var log = msg => data+= "<p>" + msg + "</p>";
    
    video.style.height ="100%";
    video.style.width ="320px";
```